# App running on docker consuming page cache of host machine.Is that anti-pattern ?

Tags: caching, docker, docker-machine

if that is the case then there is no isolation of host resource at container level?one app running on docker can overuse page cache and messing up host or other containers. Is there any chance ?

Comment: The page cache used is the hosts. A container that does a lot of different IO could cause the kernel to evict other stale data from the cache.

Comment: Matt,one app running on docker can overuse page cache and messing up host or other containers caching performance. Is that any chances ?